# Javascript Parse Error - Why?

Tags: javascript, parsing, titanium

I've been working with some arrays in javascript. I've got a parse error at this line:

```
var cardData[0] = [
    [
        'Rumble Pack',
        'Robert Mugabe',
        0.2,
        0.7,
        21,
        RuleTypes.dictatorship,
        '88%',
        '45%',
        '\'The Jewel of Africa\', Zimbabwe, returning to the stone age. R.M. let a rabble led by Chenjerai \'Hitler\' Hunzwi murder white farmers at will. 25 % of Zimbabwians HIV-positive. Life expectancy fallen 16 yrs. under R.M.'
    ]
];
```

Remember that the line is a single line, i don't know if that makes any difference...
Can someone help me? :)                    .

Comment: why enclosed in[[ ]] ? literal array should be inside single brackec [ ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var cardData[0]` doesn't work like that.  Do this instead:

```
var cardData = [];
cardData[0] = stuff;
```

or more simply:

```
var cardData = [stuff];
```

`var` declares a variable with a certain name, and bracket notation is not a valid in a variable name.

Comment: Ahh thats my mistake - Wierd that i didn't see that :) But thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign the value (in your case array) to the first element of array before creating the array first. You can try to change it to:

```
var cardData = [];
cardData[0] = [
  [
    'Rumble Pack',
    'Robert Mugabe',
    0.2,
    0.7,
    21,
    RuleTypes.dictatorship,
    '88%',
    '45%',
    '\'The Jewel of Africa\', Zimbabwe, returning to the stone age. R.M. let a rabble led by Chenjerai \'Hitler\' Hunzwi murder white farmers at will. 25 % of Zimbabwians HIV-positive. Life expectancy fallen 16 yrs. under R.M.'
]];
```

Also `RuleTypes` element has to be defined somewhere in your code.